# Issues handling YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MM:SS date format

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a date column on my DB table, the value of two rows is **"01/01/2017 23:59:59"**, for my needs, I have to show this column in the **"YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MM:SS"** format.

```
BDEX    CAQ   *01/01/2017 23:59:59*
RBCP    CAQ   *01/01/2017 23:59:59*
```

When I execute this query:

```
SELECT CODE_TCT, LIB_TCT, 
To_char(D_FIN,'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH:mm:ss') AS D_FIN,
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

I get this result:

```
BDEX    CAQ   *2017-01-01T11:12:59*
RBCP    CAQ   *2017-01-01T11:01:59*
```

Why the values of the result (2017-01-01T**11:12:59** and 2017-01-01T**11:01:59**) are different knowing that they have same

I'm using Oracle 11g.

Comment: I don't see how the same timestamp (in any format/representation) could generate two different other timestamps, using the same function call.

Comment: Is the datatype `date`, or is it something like `timestamp with time zone`?

Comment: `HH` means hour in 12-hour format (typically in conjunction with AM/PM). Use `HH24`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your date mask like this:

```
SELECT CODE_TCT, LIB_TCT, 
To_char(D_FIN,'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH24:MI:SS') AS D_FIN,
FROM MY_TABLE;
```